# Looking for supernatural romance novel about woman at mental institution with mysterious power, has variation of "witch" in title

Tags: story-identification, powers, cover-art, witches

This book I recalled seeing at a nursing home one day and it's been on my mind ever since. As best I can recall, the plot involves a woman going to live at what sounded like a mental/medical institute or center following the death of someone she was related to, either her family or someone she was in love with. While at the center she begins to realize she has a mysterious power and begins to learn how to control it with the help of a male stranger.

As I can recall the cover artwork included the woman sitting or standing in front of a tree while the male character stood in the background. The sky was something of an orange color, like it was at sunset.

I think the title had a variant of the word "witch." "Witching," "Bewitching," "Witchery," something like that.

Judging from the cover I think it was published some time between 1980 and 1999. It definitely wasn't published recently.

Comment: Searching for works with "wirch" in title at [isfdb.org](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=witch&type=All+Titles) returns nearly 5000 titles. Can you help us narrow your search a little?

Comment: I could tell from the cover it wasn't a new book. The art on the cover looked like it was published sometime between 1980 and 1999.

Comment: Date-wise it cannot be "Stealing Snow" by Danielle Paige, though that story checks some four of the boxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Joe L. I found the name of the book. It's *[Witchlight](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/84539.Witchlight)* by Marion Zimmer Bradley.

> Winter Musgrave's past is largely blank, her memories missing or tissue-thin. She seem to be possessed--objects shatter when she passes, the corpses of animal appear on her doorstep. And she has the terrible feeling that something horrible happened in her empty past--results of which are now haunting her with unbridled fury.
>
> Seeking help, Winter turns to Truth Jourdemayne and learns that the key to unlocking her lost memories lies within herself--and in the magickal circle of friends in college. But the circle was broken long ago. Winter must reconstruct it is she is to save her life.